Android FullScreenIntent Restrictions: Behavior by Target SDK and Android Version
I’m trying to understand how FullScreenIntent (FSI) behavior changes based on Target SDK and Android version.
FSI Behavior by Target SDK (official documentation):
targetSdkVersion 33 or below:

FSI is allowed on Android 13 or lower if the app has notification permissions.

targetSdkVersion 34 or above:

FSI is restricted on all versions by default.
Google revokes permissions for apps that are not calling or alarm apps. An appeal may be required.

FSI Behavior by Device Version (official documentation):
Android 14 or above:

FSI is restricted, and permissions are revoked for apps without calling or alarm functionality.

Android 13 or below:

FSI works by default as long as notification permissions are granted.

Questions

Is the above theory accurate?


When does Google Play Store revoke FSI permissions? Could there be cases where the permission is not revoked?


How can developers check if the FSI permission has been revoked?
On Android 13, does the update to targetSdkVersion 34 affect FSI usability?
Can FSI work without notification permissions under certain conditions (e.g., cached processes)?

